# Why is it always runs the callback function as TRUE?

Tags: javascript

There is a function with **callback:**

```
function _isBanned(idUser, idFriend, callback){
        redis.sismember("user.friend_tmp:" + idFriend, idUser, function(err, friends){
            console.log(friends);
            if(friends == 0) { return callback(true); }
            callback(false);
        });
    }
```

**Function call:**

```
isBanned(data.from, data.to, function() {
   // BODY
}
```

Despite the fact that `console.log (friends);` is equal to **1**, the function is executed, and transfers control to the // BODY ...

Comment: UM, you call the callback no matter what... `callback(false);` is triggered... If you do not want it to be triggered, than why are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your callback regardless of the value of your `if` test.  You are passing it `true` in one case and `false` in the other case, but calling the callback in both cases.  Then, inside the callback you aren't paying any attention to any arguments passed to the callback so thus you get no different behavior in the two cases.

Perhaps your code should be this:

```
isBanned(data.from, data.to, function(banned) {
   if (banned) {
       // one action here
   } else {
       // different action here
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`callback(false);` still calls the callback function with `false` as its argument. Simply omit this line if you don't want to call the callback. Or you can handle it inside (for example, if you want to make sure your function reached the end), for example:

```
isBanned(data.from, data.to, function(arg) {
   if (arg === false) {
      alert('hey, the callback function is called, but the argument is false');
      return;
   }
   // BODY
}
```